# const int * is incompatible with const int (*)[10]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion

I am trying to understand why the following code does not work:

```
void printArray(const int(*array)[10])
{
    cout << sizeof(array) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int arr[10] = { 1, 2 };
    const int* ptrArr = &arr[0];
    printArray(ptrArr);
}
```

`const int(*array)[10]` -> array is a pointer to an array with 10 elements of type `const int`.

At first, I thought I could invoke the function with just `arr`, but it didn't work. Maybe the reason it does not work in this case is because `arr` doesn't point to an array, it points to the first element in an array.

That's why I decided to define a pointer, pointing to the first element of the array. What's the issue now though?

Comment: `arr[0]` is `const int` so `&arr[0]` is `const int*`. Basically, `ptrArray` is `const int*` and the parameter is of type `const int(*)[10]`

Comment: You have an array. You want a pointer to it. The usual way to do it is to just add `&`.

Comment: The function wants a pointer to an array, so give it a pointer to the array, not a pointer to an element of the array: `printArray(&arr)`

Comment: By the way: the `sizeof` in the `PrintArray()` gives the size of the pointer, not the actual array.

Comment: Stop using "C" style arrays like this. C++ has std::array which allows you to handle arrays like any other object e.g. . `void printArray(const std::array<int,10>& values)` and then you use `std::array<int,10> values{1,2}; printArray(values);`

Comment: `arr` does not point to an array, or to the first element of an array, it *is* an array (i.e. it is not a pointer at all).

Comment: It's unclear what your goal is, I fear that you're going down the wrong path. You certainly wouldn't normally declare a function like `void printArray(const int(*array)[10])` if your goal was to print a C array.

Answer (score 1):

> At first, I thought I could invoke the function with just arr, but it didn't work. Maybe the reason it does not work in this case is because **arr doesn't point to an array, it points to the first element in an array.**
>
> That's why **I decided to define a pointer, pointing to the first element of the array**.

And what was changed?:) In both cases, you have a pointer of the type `const int *` that points to the first element of the array.

You need to pass a pointer to the whole array like this:

```
printArray( &arr );
```

And within the function, you should dereference the passed pointer:

```
void printArray(const int(*array)[10])
{
    cout << sizeof( *array ) << endl;
                    ^^^^^^
}
```

Otherwise, the function will output the size of the pointer itself instead of the size of the array.

Instead of a pointer, you could use a reference. For example:

```
void printArray(const int (&array)[10] )
{
    cout << sizeof(array) << endl;
}

//...

printArray( arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

**The type of `ptrArray` is** `const int*`( note that`arr[0]` is `const int` so the type of `&arr[0]` is `const int*`). But since the **function parameter is of type** `const int(*array)[10]` and you're passing an argument of type `const int*` and there is **no implicit conversion between the two**, we get the mentioned  error.

##### Solution

To fix this, just remove the use of subsript when taking the address of the array as shown below:

```
const int(*ptrArray)[10] = &arr; //or just auto ptrArray = &arr;
printArray(ptrArray); //works
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I fix that, though? I am not sure I see it

Comment: @SAQ See the updated answer which shows a fix.